# bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xa871560: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now

Tags: iphone, ios

I get following bad access error when I try to push one of my view controller. Its a random error, it occurs sometime. There is one class in which I use `CFRunLoopRun();`, once I push that class then only this error comes. I am trying but still the issue is not fixed.

Let me show you code where I have used `CFRunLoopRun();`. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xa871560: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   0x5068c88 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
2   0x2eb6afe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
3   0x2eb6a3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers
4   0x2e94704 __CFRunLoopRun
5   0x2e93f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   0x2e93e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   0x5068c50 RunWebThread(void*)
8   0x9465a5b7 _pthread_start
9   0x94644d4e thread_start


 [self fatchAllEvent];
     CFRunLoopRun();   // i want to wait until above method get executed 

-(void)fatchAllEvent{

     events = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {

                  [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {

             if (granted)
             {                 
                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(waitAsItoldYou)
                                        withObject:nil
                                     waitUntilDone:YES];

                    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetMain());

                // NSLog(@"LOOP has STOP");
                               }
         }];
    }
}
```

Everything else works perfectly but something this error occurs. I have read through solutions for similar issues faced by people, but none of them were helpful. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

There was table which i was reloading and error was coming. The tableView `reloadData` command is also not thread-safe.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```